# Install Git on Mac

Tags: git, macos

I can't download Git on my computer (Mac).

I'm using the

brew install git

command but it only shows a warning.

Any thoughts?
[Git warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdlYk.png)

Comment: Make sure to update brew before installing git. `brew update`

Comment: Show the warning as text, not image

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `brew` requires you to install developer command line tools (`sudo xcode-select --install`) which includes `git`. Also, isn't `brew` depending on `git` to actually work?

Answer (score 2):

###### Solutions

There are several ways to install git on a macOS machine:

1. You can install [git-osx-installer](https://github.com/timcharper/git_osx_installer/releases/tag/2.2.1). Then use the following command to check the installation:
2. The other way to install git indirectly is to install an [XCode](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) editor. XCode contains the binary data necessary to run `git`.

---

###### Test

You can run the following command to test the installation:

```sh
git --version
```

---

###### References

- [Atlassian Git Tutorials - Install Git on Mac OS X](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git)
- [Git Official Website - Download for macOS](https://git-scm.com/download/mac)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `brew update` and also search for formulae or casks using `brew search git`